# htaccess second rewrite rule not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a website and placed this code in the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule  (.*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  (.*)$ category.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now, the first Rewrite rule works as expected, allowing me to have urls like `site.com/profile` instead of `site.com/profile.php?id=foo..` but, when I added the second one, to achive the same result as the above solution, the page breaks down, and the css does not get included. So, it seems that the two can not be writen together, and I don't know what the solution is.

Comment: The crux of the issue is that (.*) means 'everything', and the 'L' in [QSA,L] means, 'if this rule is true then stop processing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
RewriteRule  ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^category/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the 'L' from [QSA,L] on both lines?

Comment: Just added a couple of slashes, try that.

Comment: Still does not work, but I'm trying to get around that. I don't know what the `^` at all. Can you please link me a good beginner tutorial.

Comment: Just found this, does it help? http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Ahh, I had seen that. Good tutorial, but I was looking for much more easier :). Anway, thanks. It worked for me.